# Lua - same result of using and not using "self"

Tags: function, lua, self

Ok here goes...

I have been experimenting on various examples of declaring functions with "self" in the parameters.

I don't have full understanding of this which is what I'm trying to fully understand. I'm a complete beginner, but I am compelled to grasp this fully.

The 2 examples below return the same results, although in example 2, if I don't declare "self = {}" within the function, I need to place "self" (or the ":") in the function parameters for it to work. Is this the whole deal with "self"?

Are there other implications when using "self"?

**Example 1**

```
function Character.new(x)

  self = {}

  self.name = x

  return self.name

end



a = Character

b = Character

hobbit = a.new ("Frodo")

dragon = b.new ("Smaug")



print (hobbit)

print (dragon)
```

**Example 2**

```
Character = {}

function Character:new(x)

  self.name = x

  return self.name

end



a = Character

b = Character

hobbit = a:new ("Frodo")

dragon = b:new ("Smaug")



print (hobbit)

print (dragon)
```

;^)
Zalokin

Comment: `self` is nothing but an implicit first parameter that appears when you define a method with `:` notation. Since it's not a keyword, you can always declare it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` lets you access the table which includes the function from within the function without an explicit (first argument) pass. It can be used both when defining and calling a function.

The example below contains a table `t`. The table has 3 functions (`a`,`b` and `c`) and a string entry under the key `greeting`.

All the function/method calls print the same string "hello user".

Notice how you can still call a method (a function which has its container table as the first argument) the same way as a normal function, but you have to explicitly pass the table as the first argument.

The `self` argument can be called what ever you want and you can still call the function with a `:` as long as you use the correct argument name inside the function (not `self` in this case). The function `c` serves as an example of that.

It is basically just syntax sugar.

```
local t = {}

t.greeting = "hello"

function t:a(name)
  print(self.greeting, name)
end

function t.b(self, name)
  print(self.greeting, name)
end

function t.c(myself, name)
  print(myself.greeting, name)
end

t.a(t, "user")

t:a("user")

t.b(t, "user")

t:b("user")

t.c(t, "user")

t:c("user")
```

Comment: I'm finally beginning to understand the whole thing.

Comment: This is my thought process, so please bear with me... when the function is called - t points to the object t. The object is fed in the function parameter "self" (or whatever) and points to the t object itself. When the function prints, it takes into account the object t and prints out the field under greeting...

Comment: I just devised a simpler example  - `t = {}

t.greeting = "hello"

function t.a(z,name)
  print(z.greeting, name)
end


a1 = t

a2 = t

a3 = t


a1:a("user 1")

a2:a("user 2")

a3:a("user 3")`

Answer (score 2):

You're using global variables when you should be creating instances.

Try these lines instead, they may help you understand:

```
-- example 1
print (hobbit)
print(self.name)
print (dragon)
print(self.name)
```

and

```
-- example 2
print (hobbit)
print(Character.name)
print (dragon)
print(Character.name)
```

Comment: This gets weirder and weirder! If i use Example 1 with self.name as the variable in the function, the program works. But not in example 2 (it stops at `print(self.name)`. However, with `Character.name` as the variable in the function, both examples work (i.e using the `:` or the `.`). Now I'm even more confused